# Creating threads to download a file and make a counter java

Tags: java, multithreading, inputstream

Im trying to make a program that downloads a file. While downloading the file there needs to have a basic counter which counts from start to end. These two functions need to be in their own threads. I have created a method/thread to download the file. I'm having trouble figuring out how to make a basic counter. Nothing fancy but it needs to count up and only display the current number. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;
import static myutilites.methods.*;


public class Downloader
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String filename = "Nexus5MahdiRom.zip";
    URL link = new URL(
    "http://files.mahdi-rom.com/OnePlus%20One/"
    + "OnePlus%20One%20Builds/mahdi-2.7-bacon-20140903.zip");

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            try 
            {
                downloadFile(filename,link);
            } catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try {
                counter(link, t1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    t1.start();
    println("Downloading File...");
}

public void getScreenSize()
{
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension d = tk.getScreenSize();
    println("width = " + d.width + " height = " + d.height);
}
public static void downloadFile(String fileName, URL link) throws IOException
{
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(link.openStream());
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte [] buf = new byte[1024];
    int n = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while (-1 !=(n=in.read(buf)))
    {
        out.write(buf, 0, n);
    }
    println(count);
    out.close();
    in.close();

    byte[] response = out.toByteArray();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    fos.write(response);
    fos.close();

    println("Download Finished");
}
public static void locate(int row, int col)
{
    System.out.print("\033["+row+";"+col+"H");
}
public static int counter(URL link, Thread t1) throws IOException
{
    int count = 0;
    link.openConnection();
    while(t1.isAlive())
    {
        count++;
        return count;
    }
    return count;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getAndIncrement` or `incrementAndGet` on [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), which is a thread-safe counter (with the counter initialized to 0, if two threads simultaneously call `incrementAndGet` then you're guaranteed that the counter will return 1 to one thread and 2 to the other thread, and will have a final state of 2)

Comment: i tried this but when i prints to the screen it just keeps display numbers. I want the new number to erase the old number. I don't want the whole count displayed while the download is going. Just one number, erase that number, then next number.

Comment: @user3242607 Define the AtomicInteger at the same place that you define `filename` and `link`, and pass it as a parameter to `counter`.  Change `counter` to a `void` method, since you're passing the AtomicInteger by reference